# Conditional Rendering,use-timeout Invalid hook call React

Tags: reactjs, timeout, react-hooks, use-state, conditional-rendering

When check is true I want to display Next button.I get errors like unexpected token,invalid hook call.
Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
import React from "react";
import useTimeout from "use-timeout";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { check: true };

  handleCheck = () => {
    this.setState({ check: !this.state.check });
  };
  render() {
    useTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000);
    return (
      <div>
      {
       if(this.state.check){
        return <button>Next</button> 
      }
     }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: React hooks are only valid in functional components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this instead:

`<div> {this.state.check && <button>Next</button> </div>`

and remove `useTimeout` you don't need it and you CANT use it either as it's a hook and you're using a class component. You should trigger it by `onClick` instead or if you insist on using a timeout use `setTimeout` but I wouldn't advise using that inside render

use a `timeout` like this:

```
componentDidmount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000); 
}
```

Comment: I actually want to use timeout. I am trying something else this is just a trial. Can please tel me how to use timeout please. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Hey.I tried using setTimeout but nothing changed so I did console.log("hi") inside handleCheck(). Hi is printed continuosly infinite times. I dont know where else to use the setTimeout function so i used it inside the render function sorry.Could you please help

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya updated again. use inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: Hey I did exactly what you said.Now I am not getting the error but nothing is changing.

Comment: can you check `this.handleCheck();` is being called by doing a `console.log('calling')` inside it?

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya please check this? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-nll2z?file=/index.js

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya no worries! please upvote and accept answer if you found helpful. I will upvote question for you :)

Comment: Just one small doubt if I want to call setTimeout(() => {
      this.handleCheck();
    }, 10000); on clicking next button how do I do it?

Comment: put it in another function and then call that function from button click. it will trigger the timeout. please mark the question as correct and if that doesn't work ask another one and I'd be happy to help :)

Comment: Thank you so much!.It is giving an Cannot read property 'handleCheck' of undefined.

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya I would ask a new question and tag me in the comments and I would be happy to help you again :)

Comment: Okay how do i tag?

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya I have answered :)